# Create bootable disc

Tags: installation

I have created a bootable cd of the latest server version 32bit as the machine I'm installing to is only a 32bit machine. During install receive the message cannot mount CD
I cannot create a bootable desktop version as the download file is 707mb. I did try putting this onto a DVD and got the same error.
I am unable to use a memory stick as the usb ports appear to be faulty. 
I have the latest version on cd from the Linux mag but this is a 64bit version.

What are my options please?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not using a CD-RW or DVD RW as you can't boot from those.

Make sure when creating the CD-R or DVD-R to close the disc. If you burn the disc so it can be added to, it's not bootable. Which app did you use to make the boot disc, and what were the questions/options in the process and what did you answer?

Comment: I'm using DVD+R and Free ISO burner 1.2 and told the software to finalize the disc. I search for the desired iso file, the software automatically detects my burner and disc type. Burn speed max and finalize the disc.

Comment: Have just tried with a new disc and now get: error loading operating system.